# Has anyone made a Lightware SF10/A laser altimeter driver?

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It comes with a USB interface and terminal program in Windows is available.  I believe there is just one message at up to 32 Hz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194381/has-anyone-made-a-lightware-sf10/a-laser-altimeter-driver?/) by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We now have a basic one available (using cereal).  Let us know if you are interested.  The sensor works very nicely.

---

Originally posted by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) with karma: 31 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-04**:
Do you have the code in a repository somewhere?

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-03-04**:
Just added it here.
https://github.com/stevenwaslander/ros_lightware

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-04**:
Nice. Thanks. Is the `cereal` pkg you included in any way different from the standard one?

**Comment by [Timo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21625/timo/) on 2015-03-04**:
Hi, the cereal package is used to read out the messages from the /dev/ttyUSB0 device. This is a catkinized version. I believe the one on wiki.ros.org is not.
cheers Timo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-05**:
Right, indeed. According to [rosindex/cereal_port](http://rosindex.github.io/p/cereal_port/) there are indeed no registered catkin versions. Perhaps you would be interested in releasing the one you migrated?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-05**:
One of the authors (Gonçalo Cabrita) of `cereal` apparently has a catkinized version on his [github account](https://github.com/goncabrita/cereal_port).

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-03-05**:
Thanks, have moved our catkinized version to a separate repo, likely very similar.
https://github.com/stevenwaslander/cereal_port

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2016-02-11**:
Will the same for SF-40/C. Asked here http://answers.ros.org/question/226362/ros-driver-for-lightware-sf-40c-laser-scanner/